# Редирект(переадресация) с изменением рефера

Tags: редирект, ссылки

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно написать пере адресацию. нам нужно спрятать прямые ссылки на картинки, изображение должно ставиться на сторонних ресурсах только по тем кодам, что мы даем.
Есть ссылка на картинку, идущая со стороннего сайта. Но она "липовая", а не прямая. Наш сервер должен сделать редирект так, чтобы картинка появилась на стороннем сайте
нужен редирект(переадресация) с изменением рефера

Answer (score 1):

Вообще вариантов не так много придётся на своём сервере сделать какой-нибудь HTTPClient получить картинку (GET по прямому url) и в Response записать.

Так работает HTTP, если сделать обычный redirect, т.е. ответить с кодом 302 Found, то на клиенте будет прямой url к картинки.

Comment: спасибо, попробуем